# Trying to properly implement both sum and clip list operations within python

Tags: python, list, sum, clip

Evening everyone, 
I've  been having a good amount of issue trying to understand the proper way of compiling and defining list operations within python, but in this particular circumstance focusing more of sum and clip list functions.

To give a bit of context, this program obtains a set of 10 numbers inputted by a user, and runs the stored numbers through others contained in the program, such as range, average, medan, etc.. While those are already an issue in of themselves for me, I'm trying to tackle ammending the sum and clip foremost.

```
def sum (number_list) :

    for num in range ( number_list ):
    sum ( number_list )    
    return ("The sum of the numbers in this list is {}:".format(sum(number_list))) 

def clip (number_list, clipNum) :

    import numpy as np 

    in_array = number_list 
    return ("Input array : ", in_array) 

    out_array = np.clip(in_array, a_min = 1, a_max = 8) 
    return ("Output array : ", out_array)
```

The sum function is actually supposedly to second operation the user inputted number list is set to run through, and the clip functions being the final operation to run through. I'm aware that some of the code work may be a bit outdated for this version of python, or may just be incorrect in general, but at this point I'm more concerned about obtaining proper results than anything.

Comment: What do you expect, and what do you actually *get*?

Comment: Apologies about that, should've clarified that a bit better in the prompt. For the sum  I expected the numercially based list to run through it, so I could obtain a sum from each of the ten user inputted values. Explaining the clip function is a bit less straightforward, but the purpose of it is to replace all the numbers greater than the number provided to that number, which in this case would have to be specified within the clipNum. So for example if the list is [3,17,5,9,1,11] and the clipNum is 8, returned array is [3,8,5,8,1,8].

Comment: The result I actually get in the python is traceback due to supposedly undefined terms in the range function

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! So, it might be better for you to edit your question to specify not only what you expect, and what you actually get (presumably, you must be getting something unexpected, otherwise you wouldn't have a problem, right?), so that people who read your question can help you without having to trawl through the comments. Also, posting the *exact* error traceback would be better than describing it in your own terms.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `return` does. It gives a result from your function and exits it. I think you're looking for `print`

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [3,17,5,9,1,11]

def op_sum(number_list):
    return sum(number_list)

def op_clip(number_list, clip_num) :
    return [min(n, clip_num) for n in number_list]

print("sum  =", op_sum(lst))
print("clip =", op_clip(lst, 8))
```

Prints:

```
sum  = 46
clip = [3, 8, 5, 8, 1, 8]
```